# Will R auto install SystemRequirements: for users that don't have that program already

Tags: r, package

**When a user installs a package with a SystemRequirements: and they don't already have the program/package installed will R install it?**

The **clipr** package is perfect example of this question: https://github.com/mdlincoln/clipr/blob/master/DESCRIPTION. If a package declares a **SystemRequirements:** in the 'DESCRIPTION' file will it be installed by R for checking?

***clipr DESCRIPTION File***

```
Package: clipr
Type: Package
Title: Read and Write from the System Clipboard
Version: 0.2.0.9000
Authors@R: c(
  person("Matthew", "Lincoln", email = "matthew.d.lincoln@gmail.com", role = c("aut", "cre")),
  person("Louis", "Maddox", role = "ctb"))
Description: Simple utility functions to read from and write to the Windows,
  OS X, and X11 clipboards.
Imports: utils
SystemRequirements: xclip (http://sourceforge.net/projects/xclip/) or xsel
  (http://www.vergenet.net/~conrad/software/xsel/) for accessing the X11
  clipboard
License: GPL-3
LazyData: TRUE
Suggests: testthat
URL: https://github.com/mdlincoln/clipr
BugReports: https://github.com/mdlincoln/clipr/issues
```

I have consulted the [Writing R Extensions section on the DESCRIPTION file](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#The-DESCRIPTION-file) and can't find the answer to my question.

Comment: I think `nloptr` package does this automatically on *nix platforms. It downloads and installs the NLopt library. But needs manual installation on Windows.  But I don't have the details on how it is coded.

Comment: How exactly would R go about doing that?  I am 99% sure that R has no way to do this.  There are certain packages that will check to see if the necessary programs/requirements are installed and if not offer to download and install them but that would need to be coded by the package author.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. In general R won't do that because how could it?  The SystemRequirements is a text field with no specification that could tell R how to install the requirement on any given system.

There are some packages that will after their installation check to see if the other requirements are present on the system and offer to download and install them for the user but that is entirely up to the package author and is not guaranteed.

If you want some proof you'll just have to believe me but I installed clipr on my system and neither xsel or xclip were installed in the process.  I think a lot of people can also attest to having Java issues because Java doesn't automatically get installed when rJava is installed.

Comment: I concur as well on the Java thing.  Plus I totally believe you.

Comment: As I said in my (unread) comment, `nloptr` package shows an example of automatic installation of system library on *nix platform.

Comment: @Pascal And even that package doesn't list nlopt in the SystemRequirements :D

Comment: @Dason  I told you it is automatically installed. ;-)

Comment: I think we keep missing each other's points here.  I understand what you're saying but it's also only auto installed for *nix (which yes you point out).  The question was about whether things in SystemRequirements get auto installed and it's clear that they aren't.  IMO nlopt should be listed as a system requirement and it isn't (but it's still auto installed on *nix so clearly SystemRequirements isn't what causes the auto install).

Comment: @Dason  Yes, this is the point. I never saw any listed SystemRequierements get automatically installed. And yes, NLopt should be listed in SystemRequirements. My comment was to point out that it is possible to auto install a system library. But, as far as I know, there is no procedure to read the SytemRequirements section and install missing system library.

Comment: would anyone know of a preferred way to do this? specifically i would like our R pkg (only for internal use) to additionally install docker on the client machine and i am wondering what would be a good way to do this. a pointer to some reference code would be much appreciated.

Comment: As I understand **nloptr** can "autoinstall" as said by @user3710546. Yet the package comes with the source of (a certain version of) **NLopt**, so the required sources are not downloaded during the install. It would be possible to write an R package that downloads and installs, but I believe that it would never be on CRAN.